# Computer automatically disconnects from wifi: I have to restart to get back online

Tags: 14.04, wireless, networking, lenovo, realtek

My Lenovo Ideapad G50-70 will automatically disconnect from the Internet at random moments on 14.04. The network will first just stop working without any warning, and after a while, it will disconnect by itself. The strange thing is, I can't manage to get the computer back online without restarting the whole computer; it will not be able to connect to the network at all. Simply turning wireless/networking off and back on doesn't help at all. I've tried following old instructions to update drivers (as shown here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2080326 ), but it didn't help.

lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net:

```
~$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:380a]
Kernel driver in use: r8168
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:b736]
Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
```

It would be awesome if somebody could help me out! I really don't want to use Windows 8 instead. :/

Comment: Is it happening for both wired and wireless connections? Also post your syslog regarding this issue.

Comment: I've only used the computer with wireless connections, I'll try to check once i lose my Internet connection again. :) 
Update: I lost my connection while writing this, and plugged up with a wired connection. It works for now, but I have no idea if it will last. Sometimes I can go through hours before it stops working, and I have to lie on the floor to use a wired connection, so it might be a bit difficult to test. 
How do I see the syslog?

Comment: In fact you can do this right now. Find your wireless interface by `ifconfig` command. Lets say your wireless interface is **wlan0** then execute `cat /var/log/syslog | grep -i "wlan0"`. This will show you all the logs regarding your wireless interface on timely basis. Paste the output in [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and give us the link.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/8461360/ Here you go! It just asked me to enter the password for the network again, even though I'm online on a wired connection.

Comment: `Sep 29 22:49:32 brekkeslenovo wpa_supplicant[1142]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=10:bf:48:91:aa:34 reason=4 locally_generated=1`. As you can see something is definitely wrong. Give the command `sudo sh -c 'modprobe -r iwlwifi && modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1'` and check after that. This will disable the 802.11n capability of the adapter. I found this solution [here](http://zeroset.mnim.org/2014/04/22/unstable-wifi-connection-on-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-ctrl-event-disconnected-reason4-locally_generated1/) and the problem described is very much similar to your one.

Comment: It says the following after entering the command: rmmod: ERROR: missing module name. //
modprobe: FATAL: Error running remove command for iwlwifi // 
It's probably no biggie, but I have no idea what I'm doing.

Comment: That was my mistake. I forgot to check your question to find the adapter you are using. The command was for Intel adapters.

Answer (score 0):

After digging more i found that it's a known bug in Ubuntu for the Realtek RTL8723BE adapter. See this [bug report](http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1240940).
Also check out this closed question on [same issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457341/wifi-drops-and-wont-reconnect-until-reboot-14-04-with-rtl8723be).

Comment: Ah, okay. Thanks a lot for your efforts! It looks like a patch is right around the corner. :)
I tried updating to 14.10, that didn't help just yet, at least.

Comment: 14.10 has not been released yet, but remember 14.10 will not be a LTS release so you will get support for only 9 months whereas 14.04 is a LTS release that will be supported till april, 2019. [This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/16366/whats-the-difference-between-a-long-term-support-release-and-a-normal-release) will give you a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution, and worked perfectly on a Lenovo g40-30 so i guess it should work in other lenovo pc...

quote:

for one time test:

```
sudo rmmod ideapad_laptop
```

for working after reboot:

```
echo "blacklist ideapad_laptop" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ideapad.conf
```

found it in: [Wifi Not Working On Ubuntu 14.04 Lenovo G 50-30](https://askubuntu.com/questions/507470/wifi-not-working-on-ubuntu-14-04-lenovo-g-50-30/535976#535976)

prior to that I re-installed the module, updated the kernel to 3.16, and none of that worked.

Comment: I tried this; it got better, but not perfect; I would still have to restart every once in a while, but it was at least usable. However, with the newest updates to Ubuntu, it's now completely stable. I don't know if it's a combination of this solution and the updates or only the updates, but if anyone is having the same problems with an updated version of Ubuntu, this is worth trying. :)
Thanks a lot!