# Install Ubuntu 14.04LTS on my new toshiba laptop and remove windows 8

Tags: 14.04

I have bought a new laptop Toshiba with Windows 8 as operating system, and I wanted to change it to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS I am familiar with, but every time I tried to boot my USB and install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my laptop it was in vain, because every time appears a message of failure.

Comment: We need a little more information than this. For example: * What did the error message say?
* What were you doing when it occurred?
* What is the exact model # of your Toshiba laptop?
* How recent is your Ubuntu ISO?

Comment: Let's start from the "message of failure". Can you provide it?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a windows 8 laptop, it might be a problem with secure boot, a technology that keeps non-windows OSes from loading. I don't know if Ubuntu is able to boot with secure boot turned on or not, but turning it off is worth a try. I'm not familiar with Toshiba's UEFI BIOS, but there should be lots of guides online. Just google "disable Toshiba secure boot" and you should find something.

Best of luck!

Comment: I have already put ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my new Toshiba but the problem now do not function well as it do on other laptop sony.The problem now is with wifi I can not use it more than mn and it crush.during the test of the system  I had this(HTTP failed) and in the result of the test (requieres dependency `2013`.com.canonical.certificate.

Comment: Sounds like a driver issue. Ubuntu sometimes has driver issues on laptops because a lot of their hardware is proprietary. I'd try googling your exact model number and ubuntu to see if anything comes up.

Comment: Hi mate I already solve the problem but now I have a new problem my wifi crush after some minuts after I open my laptop and even it crushes it passes undetected and still have on the top I am still connected.And in this way I can not use my laptop as I am using only a wifi. Thanks

Comment: Hm, that's unfortunate.. Does restarting fix it? It could be that the wifi card isn't being properly woken up after the system has gone to sleep.

Comment: hi ,the problem with wifi is when I start or restart the laptop it works but after a minute or two it went off but without giving a sign cause in the menu I am still connected which is not true.I made the system test even I do not understand much ,and the result was this: HTTP failed.requires dependency 2013.com canonical.certificate.I searched in the internet and i found they are boxes one can use in many ways one of them is testing,actually i did not downloaded it cause I do not know how to use it.so please there is any help.thank you

Comment: Well, this one I'm not so sure on. I've done some research [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/596797/wifi-stop-working-after-while-on-ubuntu-14-04-2 and [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/457341/wifi-drops-and-wont-reconnect-until-reboot-14-04-with-rtl8723be) and from what I've gathered it is indeed a driver issue. It might be worth running the software updater or trying 15.10 live from cd or usb to see if your problem is fixed. If none of that works though, I'd reccomend starting a new question for this issue.